# running all examples in r package

Tags: r

I am developing a package in Rstudio. Many of my examples need updating so I am going through each one. The only way to check the examples is by running `devtools::check()` but of course this runs all the checks and it takes a while.

Is there a way of just running the examples so I don't have to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code to run all examples

```
devtools::run_examples()
```

Comment: OK. Have just gone and beaten myself up. Memo to self....read the devtools document....

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without `devtools`, admittedly it's a bit more circuitous.

```
package = "rgl"

# this gives a key-value mapping of the various `\alias{}`es 
#   in each Rd file to that file's canonical name
aliases <- readRDS(system.file("help", "aliases.rds", package=package))

# or sapply(unique(aliases), example, package=package, character.only=TRUE),
#   but I think the for loop is superior in this case.
for (topic in unique(aliases)) example(topic, package=package, character.only = TRUE)
```